# How to solve Laplacian equation 3D in spherical?

Tags: differential-equations

Laplace’s equation is:
$$ \nabla^2V=0 $$
The boundary conditions are:
$$ V(r=0)=0 $$
$$ V(r\gg a)=-E_0 \cos\theta $$

My code is:

```
DSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[r, θ, ϕ], {r, θ, ϕ}, "Spherical"] == 0, V[a, θ, ϕ] == 0, 
  V[∞, θ, ϕ] == - E0 r Cos[θ]}, 
 V[r, θ, ϕ], {r, θ, ϕ}]
```

but the output doesn't change.

How should I to solve the equation?

Comment: You should interpret this outcome as if Mathematica cannot solve the equations symbolically. You could try to solve the equations numerically with the [finite element method](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOverview.html). But this can be employed only for bounded domains. So, you would have to set it up for a sufficiently large but bounded spherical shell. Depending on what you are going to do with the solution also a boundary-element-method may be employed (not built-in into Mathematica iirc)...

Comment: For a symbolical solution, one usually tries a separation ansatz; the general solution can be expresses as superposition of products of Bessel functions in $r$ with spherical harmonics in $(\theta, \varphi)$.